# Error in search terms

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, product

I would like to get some help. My site, when searching for something, does not match and says:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /customers/3/a/2/**********ia.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes.../assets.php on line 741

On that line is:

```
    if ( $is_product || is_post_type_archive( 'nitro-gallery' ) || is_singular( 'nitro-gallery' ) || ( is_single() && 'gallery' == $format ) || is_tax( 'gallery_cat' ) || has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'product_page' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'nivo-lightbox' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nivo-lightbox' );
    }
```

Comment: You should replace `$is_product` by [`is_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) … It should work better.

Comment: I can only guess `$post` is not an object. Verify what that contains with `var_dump($post);`

Comment: Hi guys, changing $is_product by is_product() nothing...

Comment: I do not understand the var_dump($post); 
What should i do?

Comment: you could simply try adding the conditions in your if statement one by one until you get the culprit.

Comment: I seems to be easy, but i do not understand how to do it

Comment: Start with `if ( $is_product){` and if that works try `if ( $is_product || is_post_type_archive( 'nitro-gallery' ){` etc.

Comment: I erase all of that line and use the Advance wooCommerce Search plugin, it works perfect :)

Comment: nice but you still need to find the one that gives you the error.

Answer (score 0):

add below line before  the if statement :

```
global $post;
```